# How to track the position of items while scrolling in a long custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, arraylist, baseadapter

The data which is displayed from the database in the form of listview (here listview with headers having disabled onClick of headers).

I tried to display the description of the selected item from `position` of `getView()`. The list is very large so it dynamically allocates the view while scrolling & the `position` gives wrong values after scrolling

I watched [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)  video & [it states these things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9712700/2715065).

So I think I need to implement `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `onScroll()` , `onScrollStateChanged()` methods.

But how?

Code:

```
public class MainActivity1 extends ListActivity implements OnTouchListener{

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
Activity temp = this;
String []s = new String[500];
ArrayList<GS> q = new ArrayList<GS>();
CustomAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
int c=1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    if (!db.checkDatabase()) 
    {
        db.createDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }
    db.openDatabase();

    q = db.getData();

    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(q.get(0).getA_name());
    mAdapter.addItem(q.get(0).getAS_name());
    for (int i = 1; i < 460; i++) {

        if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(q.get(i).getA_name());
            c++;
        }
        mAdapter.addItem(q.get(i).getAS_name());

    }

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);        

}
 //Adapter Class
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.v("getItemId Position", ""+position);
        return position;

    }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
     //   System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                count++;
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        // We set the OnClickListener here because it is unique to every
        // item. Although views can be recycled & reused, an OnClickListener cannot be.
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder x = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                temp);
                        Log.v("position",""+position);
                               x.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setTitle(q.get(position-count).getAS_name())
                                .setMessage(q.get(position-count).getDesc_art())
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                                                    int arg1) {
                                            }
                                        });
                               AlertDialog a = x.create();
                        a.show();
                    }
                });
           } else {
            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(null);
            count++;
        }   

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
}
```

So,I am trying to display the description of the selected item in Alertdialog when `TYPE_ITEM` is clicked.The description of each TYPE_ITEM is stored in the database sequentially. Hence, I need to keep track the position(means indexing) of TYPE_ITEM for getting data from database. I hope u now understand my problem !

BTW I tried using a count variable in `getView()` that but in that what if we again scroll up(in that case the `count` should decrement). i hope u understand the problem now & i think we should implement notifyDataSetChanged or onScroll, onScrollStateChanged methods.

If the problem is not clear then u can ask me in the comments

Pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is move the setting of `OnClickListener` on `holder.textview`.

The problem here is:

: Since you set the OnClickListener in the `if (convertView == null)` block, it isn't changed 
     when **convertView is not null**. So, the `position` used in `AlertDialog` is the one you set 
     when `convertView` *was* null.

: Solution is to set the OnClickListener every time a position is processed - we don't care if 
     the view is recycled or not!!! We need to reset the OnClickListener to reflect the 
     correct/current position.

: Although, we never set an OnClickListener on holder.textview when item is `TYPE_SEPARATOR`, its 
     safe to remove the OnClickListener using `holder.textview.setOnClickListener(null)`.

Try the updated code below. I hope the logic here is quite clear.

```
//Adapter Class
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ....
    ....     
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main1, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        // We set the OnClickListener here because it is unique to every
        // item. Although views can be recycled & reused, an OnClickListener cannot be.
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
            holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder x = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                temp);
                        Log.v("position",""+position);
                               x.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setTitle(q.get(position-1).getAS_name())
                                .setMessage(q.get(position-1).getDesc_art())
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                                                    int arg1) {

                                            }
                                        });
                        AlertDialog a = x.create();
                        a.show();
                    }
              });
        } else {
            holder.textview.setOnClickListener(null);
        }   

        return convertView;
    }

    ....
    ....

}
```

**Edit:**

Wrapper class (can be implemented as an inner class of `MainActivity1` or independently):

```
public class ContentWrapper {

    private String mItem, mItemDescription;

    public ContentWrapper(String item, String itemDescription) {
        mItem = item;
        mItemDescription = itemDescription;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return mItem;
    }

    public String getItemDescription() {
        return mItemDescription;
    }
}
```

Your data-setup will also change:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    if (!db.checkDatabase()) 
    {
        db.createDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }
    db.openDatabase();

    q = db.getData();

    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();

    // mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(q.get(0).getA_name());

    // First separator item
    // No description
    mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(0).getA_name(), null));

    // mAdapter.addItem(q.get(0).getAS_name());

    // First TYPE_ITEM
    // Pass the description
    mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(0).getAS_name(), q.get(0).getDesc_art()));


    for (int i = 1; i < 460; i++) {

        if (!(q.get(i).getA_name().trim().equals(q.get(i-1).getA_name().trim()))) {
            // mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(q.get(i).getA_name());
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getA_name(), null));
            c++;
        }

        // mAdapter.addItem(q.get(i).getAS_name());
        mAdapter.addItem(new ContentWrapper(q.get(i).getAS_name(), q.get(i).getDesc_art()));
    }

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);        
}
```

Next, we make changes to the adapter:

```
// private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<ContentWrapper> mData = new ArrayList<ContentWrapper>();
```

The `add*` methods

```
public void addItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(ContentWrapper value) {
    mData.add(value);
    // save separator position
    mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ContentWrapper getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}
```

The `getView(...)` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....
    ....

    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).getItem());

    if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder x = new AlertDialog.Builder(temp);
                Log.v("position",""+position);
                       x.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

                        // .setTitle(q.get(position-count).getAS_name())
                        .setTitle(mData.get(position).getItem())

                        // .setMessage(q.get(position-count).getDesc_art())
                        .setMessage(mData.get(position).getItemDescription())

                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg,
                                            int arg1) {
                                    }
                                });
                 AlertDialog a = x.create();
                 a.show();
             }
         });
    } else {
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
}
```

And that's about it.

> [I] think we should implement notifyDataSetChanged or onScroll,
>   onScrollStateChanged methods.

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is used to tell the adapter that the underlying data has changed and thus a refresh is required. For example, if description for an item changes, you would update that item in `mData` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But in your case (and from what your code tells me), your data is initialized before you set the adapter using - `setListAdapter(mAdapter)`. So, calls to `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the `add*` methods are not even required. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` before attaching an adapter to a listview does nothing.

`onScroll` and `onScrollChanged` are meant for a different purpose. For example, say that you show a `Go To Top of the List` button when the user scroll past the 50th item - and hide it when they scroll up the 50th position. In your case, the problem was that you were trying to get data from two different sources(mData, q) and there were issues with synchronization. Nothing else.

Comment: Your solution seems to work & `position` value seems to be increasing but 'position' also increases by 'TYPE_SEPERATOR' i.e. header & i want to minus the position for every header to display the correct data ! i tried doing -1 as u can see in alertdialog but it displays the correct data under 1st header ! I have many headers in my list & for that wht sh'd be done?

Comment: @Warde Well, perhaps you can keep a `count` variable to track number of `TYPE_ITEM`? Initialize this variable to `zero` and increment it **only** when `type == TYPE_ITEM`. Now you can use this variable in your `AlertDialog`. **BUT** - I still don't understand what you're doing here. So, if you can explain that, we could find a better approach to this.

Comment: I am trying to display the description of the selected item  in Alertdialog when `TYPE_ITEM` is clicked.The description of each `TYPE_ITEM` is stored in the database sequentially. Hence, I need to keep track the position(indexing) of `TYPE_ITEM` for getting data from database. I hope u now understand my problem !
& BTW I tried using a count variable in and increment it only when type==TYPE_ITEM but what if we again scroll up(in that case the value should decrement). i hope u understand the problem now & i think we should implement notifyDataSetChanged or onScroll, onScrollStateChanged methods.

Comment: I edited my question by ur answer & added the clarification of question

Comment: @Warde The suggestion to keep a `count` variable was terrible. Apologies. Why don't you create a wrapper class that handles both the `item data` and `item description`. In case of `TYPE_SEPARATOR`, you can pass `null` or `empty string ""` for description - it doesn't matter because we're not setting an `OnClickListener` for `TYPE_SEPARATOR`. I'm adding an edit to my answer. See if implementing a wrapper solves your problem.

Comment: now i want to combine this in my App with fragments. can u pls guide how to use it in a fragment ! I have posted a new question against this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593203/using-listactivity-in-fragment

Comment: @Warde Sorry, I was busy with exams. I see that user `Raghunandan` has addressed your concerns. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the scroll position easily and smooth by putting onScrollListener to your ListvView in your Acvivity. That contains two basic methods: onScroll and onScrollStateChanged.

**EDIT**

OnScrollListener has wide range of usage. This is OnScrollListener, which detects end of scroll and loads more data. Popular load-more feature.

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                            int totalItemCount) {
                        if(mListView.getRefreshableView().getCount()!=0&&mListView.getRefreshableView().getCount()>0&&mAdapter.getCount()!=0){
                        if (mListView.getRefreshableView().getLastVisiblePosition() == mListView.getRefreshableView().getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                                && mListView.getRefreshableView()
                                .getChildAt(mListView.getRefreshableView().getChildCount() - 1)
                                .getBottom() <= mListView.getRefreshableView().getHeight()) {


                            if(SplashScreen.countie  == mAdapter.getCount()){
                                if(footie.isShown()) {
                                mListView.getRefreshableView().removeFooterView(footie);    
                                }
                            }

                            else{
                                if(loading!=true&&dontupdate==false){



                                    updateMoreData();
                                    }

                                    else{}
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                            int scrollState) {
                        //the int scrollState is what are you looking for                           

                        if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == scrollState) {
                            View currentFocus = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                            if(currentFocus != null) {
                                currentFocus.clearFocus();
                            }
                        }



                    }

                });
```

If you want to get the scroll position use `onScrollStateChanged` method. The int scrollState in code below is actually what you want. You can do whatever you want with it.

BTW
This was just a example of usage of `OnScrollListener` but what you have to do is just set it without inner setting (in my case load more feature) but just use `onScrollStateChanged` and its `int`.

hope it helps!

Comment: Can u provide more details on onScroll and onScrollStateChanged &how to use them ?

Comment: `lv`  doesnt have any impact in my code because i am using Custom Listview

Comment: so if your custom ListView extends ListView , you can set OnScrollListener also there